# Android: MalformedURLException java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found

Tags: java, android

i know it's possible duplicate this post but i read every all others post and not found solution for me. Why this URL it's cause this problem?

https://storage.sbg1.cloud.ovh.net/v1/AUTH_297cdb44e582481d87a484aafab89eae/skyhawk-videos/745201153_1476533417143.mp4

```
URL url = new URL(download_file_path.toString());
```

After this code the `url` is null!

Comment: Try using `http` instead of `https`

Answer (score 0):

Add scheme before your `url`, check if it does not bbegin with http add http or https.